# Why do so many Bitcoin websites have such bad reviews

Tags: trading

I'm very interested in starting out trading with a cryptocurrency but I've noticed every single website seems to have a low Trustpilot rating, full of one stars claiming the website is fraudulent etc. Is this just a common, untrue thing amongst Bitcoin trading sites?

Comment: You might also want to ask yourself if you really want to buy bitcoins, or if you might as well buy a certificate or future through a traditional stock trading platform. Personally I can't really see any benefit to going through the hassle and risk of using a crypto currency exchange site, unless you're planning on using your bitcoins as payment or holding on to them for a long time. These platforms are generally secure, easy to use, easy to deposit and withdraw funds from and have less fees than crypto currency exchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed a lot of fraudulent online exchanges and wallet providers. The same is true for displeased customers.

I suggest you take a tour at https://bitcointalk.org and get to known which providers are trustworthy.
For trading cryptocurrencies, I'll suggest you start with Coinbase/GDAX or blockchain.info. Then based on what coins you are interested in, find another exchange that support them.

This page is also very helpful, it list the biggest online exchanges. 
https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/volume/24-hour/